# System.loadLibrary UnsatisfiedLinkError ELF file data encoding not little-endian

Tags: java, gcc, java-native-interface, endianness

I have been following a JNI tutorial:

http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html

and my C library is successfully built but I am having problems using it.

When I run my Java program in Eclipse on OpenSuse11 I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/libfpdpReaderLib.so: /usr/lib/libfpdpReaderLib.so: ELF file data encoding not little-endian (Possible cause: endian mismatch)
```

I have tried rebuilding the library forcing "-mlittle-endian" in gcc but this fails as other libraries it uses are obviously big-endian.

Can I force java to use big-endian as the rest of the machine seems to be? Any ideas why I am getting this mismatch as I though JVM was big-endian in general?

Thanks for any help!

*Update 23/11/2011:*

The gcc is obviously compiling big-endian which matches the libraries that are included but I am confused why the Java call to System.loadLibrary is expecting little-endian as this goes against the rest of the system...

I am assuming this is because the Java will run in a JVM but from what I have read I thought that this would default to big-endian...?

Any ideas how I can change what my Java is expecting?

Comment: apart from that the errormessage should flip the description 
error-message and possible-cause ... can you print out, what a value you got in c?

Comment: @Peter I'm not entirely sure what your comment was trying to say but here is the error message when I try to rebuild my C library using "-mlittle-endian" `../ppc_74xx/lib/librt.so: could not read symbols: File in wrong format`